# JPA: How to display OneToMany data in a JSP page?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, jpa, jstl

I have to class : Student and Address , with a OneToMany relationship, so every student can have one or multiple address,

Now I try to display a given student details (its Student + its Address details) in a JSP page but only the Student information are displayed and not its address.

here is the sevlet page:

```
       @WebServlet(name = "TestServlet", urlPatterns = {"/TestServlet"})
          public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
        @EJB
        private StudentDaoLocal studentDao;

        protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {

            String studentIdStr = request.getParameter("studentId");

            if (studentIdStr != null && !studentIdStr.equals("")) {
                int studentId = Integer.parseInt(studentIdStr);

                Student student = studentActions(studentId);

                request.setAttribute("student", student);
                request.getRequestDispatcher("info.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }

        }

        private Student studentActions(int studentId)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            Student student;
            student = studentDao.getStudent(studentId);

            return student;
        }
```

the JSP page:

```
       <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
        <body>
            <h1> Student Details</h1>

                   Student Details
                <br>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Year Level</th> 
                    </tr>

                     <c:forEach>
                        <tr>  
                        <td>${student.studentId}</td>
                        <td>${student.firstname}</td>
                        <td>${student.lastname}</td>
                        <td>${student.yearLevel}</td>
                        </tr>
                </c:forEach>

            </table>  

    </br>
            Student'Adresse
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                <th>Street</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>Country</th>
                </tr>


                <h1>${student.addresses}</h1>  


                     <c:forEach items="${student.addresses}" var="address"> 
                         <tr> 
                             <td>${address.street}</td> 
                             <td>${address.city}</td> 
                             <td>${address.country}</td> 
                         </tr> </c:forEach>
            </table> 

    <br>
</body>
</html>
```

The Student class:

```
     @Entity
     @Table
     @NamedQueries({@NamedQuery(name="Student.getAll",query="SELECT e FROM Student e") })

public class Student implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column
    private int studentId;
    @Column
    private String firstname;
    @Column
    private String lastname;
    @Column
    private int yearLevel;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="student", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Address> addresses;

public int getStudentId() {
    return studentId;
}

public void setStudentId(int studentId) {
    this.studentId = studentId;
}

public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

public int getYearLevel() {
    return yearLevel;
}

public void setYearLevel(int yearLevel) {
    this.yearLevel = yearLevel;
}

public List<Address> getAddresses() {
    return addresses;
}

public void setAddresses(List<Address> addresses) {
    this.addresses = addresses;
}

public Student(int studentId, String firstname, String lastname, int yearLevel) {
    this.studentId = studentId;
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.yearLevel = yearLevel;
}

public Student(int studentId, String firstname, String lastname, int yearLevel, List<Address> addresses) {
    this.studentId = studentId;
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.yearLevel = yearLevel;
    this.addresses = addresses;
}

public Student(){}

public void addAddress(Address address){
    this.addresses.add(address);
    if(address.getStudent() != this){
        address.setStudent(this);
    }
   }
  }
```

And the Address class:

```
        @Entity
        @Table
        public class Address implements Serializable{
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column
        private int addressId;
        @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name="studentId")
        private Student student;
        @Column
        private String street;
        @Column
        private String city;
        @Column
        private String country;

public Address(){}
public Address(int addressId, String street, String city, String country) {
    this.addressId = addressId;
    this.street = street;
    this.city = city;
    this.country = country;
}

public Address(int addressId, Student student, String street, String city, String country) {
    this.addressId = addressId;
    this.student = student;
    this.street = street;
    this.city = city;
    this.country = country;
}

public Student getStudent() {
    return student;
}

public void setStudent(Student student) {
    this.student = student;
}

public int getAddressId() {
    return addressId;
}

public void setAddressId(int addressId) {
    this.addressId = addressId;
}

public String getStreet() {
    return street;
}

public void setStreet(String street) {
    this.street = street;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return street + ", " + city + ", " + country;
}
public boolean isEmptyAddress(){
    return this.getStreet().isEmpty() && this.getCity().isEmpty() && this.getCountry().isEmpty();
}
public void updateAddress(Address address){
    this.street = address.street;
    this.city = address.city;
    this.country = address.country;
}
```

here is the problem; the address part is not loaded.

1: - So now How can I print the addresses in the servlet

So now how can I check first if addresses are being loaded before student object is passed to the jsp?
A friend tell me that I can printing the addresses in the servlet but I dont know how to do that.

2: - is the JSP code ok to display the an student's address?

(between, am new in Java EE world so...)

[image: the JSP page]

Answer (score 0):

To see if the addresses are being populated you can do this in the servlet:

```
Student student = studentActions(studentId);
if(student.getAddresses() != null) {
    for(Address address : student.getAddresses()) {
        System.out.println(address);
    }
}
```

The jsp code has an extra `<c:forEach>` tag in the part that prints the student information, that should be removed. The outer `<c:forEach>` doesn't have the `collection` or `var` attributes specified, if that's how your actual code is it's not going to print anything.

```
<c:forEach>
    <tr> 
        <c:forEach> <!-- REMOVE THIS -->
            <td>${student.studentId}</td>
            <td>${student.firstname}</td>
            <td>${student.lastname}</td>
            <td>${student.yearLevel}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: OK, thanks, I've removed the extra foreach, the collection and the var attributes, but it still dont display the adress part in the JSP page. BUT, I now I can see that the addresses are being populated in the output,

Comment: Try just putting something like `<h1>${student.addresses}</h1>` on the page to see if the addresses are populated.

Comment: OK, now it display the address but in that format:  {[DavidStreet, DavidCity, DavidCountry]}

Comment: So now how can I display the address int the table?

Comment: Your address loop should work if it looks *exactly* like this `<c:forEach items="${student.addresses}" var="address">
                    <tr>
                        <td>${address.street}</td>
                        <td>${address.city}</td>
                        <td>${address.country}</td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>`

Comment: Well I think that's what i did before but it don't display nothing,

Comment: It's clear that the student and his address list are both making it to the page since `${student.addresses}` printed correctly, so now it can only be a syntax error somewhere with the `<c:forEach>` loop. If you update the question by pasting in the *exact* code from your jsp page I may be able to help.

Comment: OK, I've Just edited the post with the Image and the JSP code changed.

Comment: It looks like `addresses` isn't a list. What does it print if you change `<h1>${student.addresses}</h1>` to `<h1>${student.addresses.class}</h1>`.

Comment: It give me error message : org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "class" ---- here is a dropbox link of the project, if it can help you to help me, is.gd/4jB0Lh

Comment: Hi, You have a solution about the problem?